# DotNetCore, Prism 7, WPF - Service Not Being Created

Tags: wpf, .net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, prism

I'm using DotnetCore, WPF and Prism 7 to make a desktop application.  I have one service called `DbConnectionService` that doesn't seem to be created.  This service is not injected into any component that is reachable through the View tree(?).  Instead, it listens to the `IEventAggregator` and communicates with the rest of the app through that.

I'm finding that I'm not able to get it to 1. be created, and 2. if it is created it doesn't stick around (GC I assume).

Below is the code I have "shotgunning" anything that will create the DbConnectionService.  All to no avail.

```
containerRegistry.RegisterInstance(typeof(DbConnectionService), "DbConnectionService");
containerRegistry.Register<IDbConnectionService, DbConnectionService>();
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton(typeof(DbConnectionService));
containerRegistry.GetContainer().RegisterSingleton<DbConnectionService>();
```

Any help on getting this service to be created and stick around is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This service is not injected into any component

That's why it's not created. Either you inject it and rely on the container's magic to create it, or you create it yourself.

You can use the container to keep the object alive (i.e. not garbage collected) through `RegisterInstance`:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterInstance( containerRegistry.GetContainer().Resolve<DbConnectionService>() );
```

Note that `Resolve` isn't on `IContainerRegistry` to prevent you from doing this, because you don't want to mix registering and resolving. If you have to, make 110% sure that all dependencies of `DbConnectionService` are registered beforehand.